# OpenWRT seems to working but canot be configured

Tags: router, telnet, wifi-configuration, openwrt

I installed openwrt on TP-Link TL-WR841ND v11. When it booted, lock diode didnť turn off (when on router was standart firmware led rurned off after boot)  and leds indicated connected computers show.

**I can:**
ping the router, 
communicate by switch between computers

**I cant:**
access router web GUI, 
access telnet

Is there any way to configure router? It seems like it works by canť access any configuration interface.

Comment: You should perform a hard factory reset.

Comment: How I can to do it?

Comment: http://www.tp-link.us/faq-497.html

Comment: or https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/generic.failsafe